# Value of object displayed correctly in console but not in browser

Tags: node.js

I have an issue displaying the values of my object in the browser, here is my object:

websites.js

```
module.exports = [
    {
        url: 'value1',
        timeout: 15
    },

    {
        url: 'value2',
        timeout: 15
    }
];
```

and here is my simple server:

app.js

```
var websites = require('./websites.js'),
    http = require('http'),
    server,
    port = process.env.PORT || 3008;

server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var data = "Monitoring the following: \n \n" + websites;
    console.log(websites);
    res.end(data);
}); 

server.listen(port);
console.log('Listening to port %s', port);
```

The console.log(websites) shows the object as

```
[{url: 'value1',timeout: 15},{url: 'value2',timeout: 15}]
```

which is fine, but when I browse http://localhost:3008/ the object is displayed as

```
[object Object],[object Object]
```

I would like my object to be displayed on the browser as it is in the console. I tried a few things like Object.values() or JSON.parse() without success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: check [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: @igormilla Yes, that works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: great. I posted it as an answer, you can accept it, to resolve this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of `[object Object]` in a console output of a browser, you should use   [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert JavaScript value into a JSON string.

Your code will looks like:

> var data = "Monitoring the following: \n \n" + JSON.stringify(websites);

Comment: wrong object stringified, can you edit your response to this blockcode and I would accept it as the right answer: `var data = "Monitoring the following: \n \n" + JSON.stringify(websites);`

Comment: sure, here you have.